# Deduplication with awk on command line and script

Tags: linux, awk, csv

I have a file that has the following format:

```
487422,Potenza
487386,Forlì-Cesena
487399,Grosseto
487425,Catanzaro
487409,Napoli
487446,Prato
495498,Fermo
487425,Catanzaro
487389,Macerata
487442,Biella
487351,Asti
487424,Cosenza
487404,Roma
487359,Como
487404,Roma
487401,Terni
487420,Brindisi
487397,Arezzo
487348,Vercelli
487382,Modena
487356,Genova
487365,Cremona
487369,Verona
487386,Forlì-Cesena
```

As you can see, it is a comma-separated text with duplicates. I would like to deduplicate the text with respect to column 1 using `awk`.

### Command line

If I use the shell interface, this is what I get

```
487422,Potenza
487386,Forlì-Cesena
487399,Grosseto
487425,Catanzaro
487409,Napoli
487446,Prato
495498,Fermo
487389,Macerata
487442,Biella
487351,Asti
487424,Cosenza
487404,Roma
487359,Como
487401,Terni
487420,Brindisi
487397,Arezzo
487348,Vercelli
487382,Modena
487356,Genova
487365,Cremona
487369,Verona
```

which is what I would expect from the following command

```
awk -F"," '!a[$1]++' filename.csv
```

### Awk script

If I use the awk script written as follows

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS=","
}
{
    {!a[$1]++}
}
```

I do not get any output. Is there something wrong with the script? Why is the behaviour different between the script and the command line?

Comment: @EdMorton I am aware of the fact that I could use sort, but I would like a solution that preserves the order and that can also be run in optimal time over thousands of records. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Do you mean that actually what awk is also doing under the hood is the same kind of operation? Because somehow doing this wrt piping sort and uniq takes a bit less time.

Comment: No, it's a different operation but sort is designed to efficiently handle large amounts of data, using demand paging as necessary, while awk is storing every key value in memory to be able to do a hash lookup of every key read and so getting slower and more likely to fail as the number of keys increases. Awk will be fine if you only have thousands of records but once you get into millions a decorate/sort/undecorate approach would probably be faster and when you get into the billions you might find you need that to be able to do the processing at all.

Comment: I added a decorate/sort/undecorate answer so you can see what that looks like.

Comment: @EdMorton, I've tried looking up "unix sort demand paging" but nothing comes up. I'd like to read up on how this works, can you point to some resources?

Comment: @ZachYoung Google "Unix sort large files" and you'll see results like http://vkundeti.blogspot.com/2008/03/tech-algorithmic-details-of-unix-sort.html and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/279099/133219.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outside of braces, `!a[$1]++` is a *condition*, which triggers the default action `{print}` if it evaluates true (non-zero).

Inside braces, `{{!a[$1]++}}` is an *action* that is evaluated unconditionally with no side effect. Remove the braces:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS=","
}

!a[$1]++
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! How about, once found the unique values in column 1, printing values in column 1,3,4? How do I combine this with the print statement? How would I be able to combine this, for example, with an if statement over a column ($2 contains string IT, for example)?

Comment: @shoyip something like `!a[$1]++ {print $1,$3,$4}` or `!a[$1]++ && $2 ~ /IT/ {print $1,$3,$4}`

Answer (score 2):

[@steeldriver's awk answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/674639/133219) is correct and is probably all you need, but if your input gets massive it may run out of memory and/or get relatively slow and in that case here's a decorate/sort/undecorate approach that will continue to work:

```
nl -w1 -s, file |       # Decorate by prefixing with line numbers
sort -ut, -k2,2 |       # Sort uniquely by the real key field
sort -nt, -k1,1 |       # Sort whats left by the line numbers we added
cut -d, -f2-            # Undecorate by removing the line numbers
```

Comment: Thanks! This would be a very nice trick in order to preserve order while selecting unique entries.